# Post an array of objects with Restangular - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, queue, restangular

I'm using Restangular to make my API call for a single object, like this:

```
$scope.box = { name : "box_a" , id : 1 };

Restangular.all('boxes/')
    .post($scope.box)
    .then(function(){
        ...
    });
```

But now, the user can select multiple boxes to add at once. So, I want to post multiple objects to my API, but I need to wait for each request until it's done, or my database will 'lock'...

My *quick-add* objects are the following:

```
$scope.boxes = [
    { name : "box_a" , id : 1 },
    { name : "box_b" , id : 2 },
    { name : "box_c" , id : 3 }
]
```

How can I create a promise chain by looping through my `$scope.boxes`? I can't quite figure out how to create an array of promises with Restangular...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about restangular, but you could chain those requests with a reduce function like:

```
$scope.boxes.reduce(function(promise, newBox){
    return promise.then(function(){

      return Restangular.all('boxes/')
             .post(newBox)
             .then(function(){
                 ...
             });
    });
  }, $q.resolve());
```

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x90b71cz/) (wihout restangular, just a post call) and it seems to work.